# Atmel Markings 58BL W 9H0336E

Tags: identification, atmel

ATMEL

MARKINGS: 58BL W 9H0336E

I have no idea what these marking indicate, can anyone here help me ID this part?

Comment: http://support.atmel.com/bin/customer.exe?=&action=newTicket

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words...

Answer (score 4):

Possibly ...

Identifying parts got a whole lot harder once the parts became too small to hold the whole part number...

The significant part of the marking will be 58BL. 0336 will be the date code (week 36, 2003)

Now searching the obvious place for ATMEL 58BL yields a lot of rubbish, and [this supplier in Poland](https://www.piekarz.pl/index.php?page=offer&item=59193) whose listing contains:

> us AT25080-SSHL Atmel SO8 SMD Pbf;ATMEL;58BL

which gives us a possible clue. AT25080 looks like a real part number, and the first search hit for Atmel AT25080 is [this datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0675.pdf) for a 1kbyte EEPROM with SPI interface in a SO8 package.

But now you're going to tell me it's in a 40-pin package and couldn't possibly be this part...

EDIT : a little more digging on Atmel's website [here](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT25080B.aspx?tab=documents) shows a newer [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc5228.pdf) for the 25080B, and this one shows the product markings : page 14 shows the code 58BL.

I'm going to guess it's probably a 25080A from the date code; unfortunately that one's datasheet again doesn't show the markings.